# When to use has_many through vs many_to_many in Ecto?

Tags: elixir, ecto

So reading [this Ecto documentation](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Schema.html#has_many/3) and this [post](https://elixirforum.com/t/many-to-many-association-table-with-extra-columns/6563/10) it looks like:

1. Both `has_many :some_schema_name, through: [...]` and `many_to_many` are backed by a separate join table
2. The only difference between the two is that you can add extra columns to the "third join table" which you can't do with a many_to_many join table.

Are there any other differences both in usage idioms and the way the data is modeled/backed by the database? It seems like you'd almost always prefer to use a has_many through relationship if you want the flexibility to add columns (or metadata) on the join table.

Comment: `has_many` is one to many and `many_to_many` is many to many.

Comment: I think you're correct - this was also true in Ruby on Rails, and I often preferred the `through` so I could give the join table a custom name and add extra fields to the relationship.

Comment: I've always found the philosophy from the RoR Guide to be helpful:          "The simplest rule of thumb is that you should set up a has_many :through relationship if you need to work with the relationship model as an independent entity. If you don't need to do anything with the relationship model, it may be simpler to set up a has_and_belongs_to_many relationship (though you'll need to remember to create the joining table in the database).

You should use has_many :through if you need validations, callbacks, or extra attributes on the join model."

Comment: `many_to_many` also uses single JOIN SQL query, while `has_many through:` doesn't.